# How to Split data frame by rows number

Tags: r, dataframe, split

I have a dataset with 8588 rows and 91 columns. I want to divide it into two new data frames but based on predetermined row numbers.

Example

First data frame

```
1 A
2 B
3 C
4 D
5 E
6 F
7 G
8 H
9 I
10 J
```

The second data frame contains the row number

```
4
7
5
1
9
```

The third data frame contains the row number

```
6
10
2
3
8
```

the result is like this

1st new data frame

```
4 D
7 G
5 E
1 A
9 I
```

2nd new data frame

```
6 F
10 J
2 B
3 C
8 H
```

The question is how to do this?
Thank you

Comment: `df1 <- subset(df, V1 %in% c(4,7, 5,1,9))` and `df2 <- subset(df, V1 %in% c(6,10, 2,3,8))` where `V1` is the column name.

Comment: Yes its work but But the result is not random only sequentially. For df1 is 1 4 5 7 9 not 4, 7, 5, 1, 9.

Answer (score 0):

We can `subset` the dataframe based on values and then `match` and `order`.

```
df1 <- subset(df, V1 %in% c(4,7, 5,1,9))
df2 <- subset(df, V1 %in% c(6,10, 2,3,8))

df1 <- df1[order(match(df1$V1, c(4,7, 5,1,9))), ]
df1
#  V1 V2
#4  4  D
#7  7  G
#5  5  E
#1  1  A
#9  9  I

df2 <- df2[order(match(df2$V1, c(6,10, 2,3,8))), ]
df2
#   V1 V2
#6   6  F
#10 10  J
#2   2  B
#3   3  C
#8   8  H
```